# LINQ Query returning result set twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using this query to populate a drop down list on my ASP.NET page:

```
using (CountriesRegionsDataContext db = new CountriesRegionsDataContext())
        {
            ddlCountry.Items.Clear();
            ddlCountry.DataSource = from c in db.CountryCodes orderby c.CountryName select c;
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryCode1";
            ddlCountry.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
            ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select a country -", "0"));
        }
```

The data source is a simple SQL table which contains no duplicates. However when my page renders, the bound data is repeated twice in the drop down list control (a-za-z).

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going on? Using distinct() doesn't seem to solve the problem (and there is no duplicate data in the table), and I tried adding ToList() to the end of my query and that doesn't seem to be fixing it either.

Comment: Check your DB table again.

Comment: Any chance that code is executing twice? What happens if you comment out the last line?

Comment: @rsbarro It's clearing the items first, so if it was called twice it would be twice as slow, but still work.

Comment: If you switch "AppendDataBindItems" to false, does the problem go away?

Comment: @Servy You're right, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @BillGregg In theory, since there are no items (he cleared them all) it shouldn't matter if you're appending or replacing...at least I'd hope so.

Comment: @Servy, Agreed.  But since the whole thing isn't behaving like we'd have thought, changing just one piece and seeing how that change behaves could lead us to a solution.

Comment: I commented out the last line and it is still doing the same thing. I actually added the Clear() line to check if the code was executing twice.

Comment: @BillGregg, I decided to test your theory, and apparently not setting AppendDataBoundItems to true solves the problem. The question I have now is why...

Comment: @ElGavilan Because the values were already in the list box once.  Now why they were already in the list box is your next question.  :)

Comment: @ElGavilan what that means is that somewhere, later on in the page's lifecycle, something is calling `ddlCountry.DataBind()` *again*, which causes the control to add the contents of the data source to the list a second time.

Comment: Items.Clear is clearing the actual items from the front-facing list, but not the databound list on the back end - which is why settingAppendDataBoundItems to false works, otherwise you're clearing the items, but then duplicating the back end.

Comment: Or that theory could be totally wrong and @AdamMaras is correct. Either way, a trip to the debugger is in order :)

Comment: So...I re-added `AppendDataBoundItems = true` and debugged. The query does not produce a duplicate result. Which means that DataBind is being called twice (thanks @AdamMaras). Only problem now is how am I going to add in my `- select a country -` line without AppendDataBoundItems?

Comment: So, if `DataBind` is being called later on... why not just let it happen? Set `AppendDataBoundItems` to `true` and remove the call to `DataBind`. (Also, figure out why `DataBind` is being called later. That doesn't sound like expected behavior to me.)

Comment: @AdamMaras Removing the call to `DataBind` worked. Now I gotta find out why it is being called later. At least it works now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing Adam Maras comment and posting as an answer:

What that means is that somewhere, later on in the page's lifecycle, something is calling `ddlCountry.DataBind()` again, which causes the control to add the contents of the data source to the list a second time.

Comment: You figured out the what, I figured out the why. Yay, teamwork!